# how to remove extra "25" from url after redirection from http to https (hebrew encoding)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i'm having a really big problem of removing some added numbers that appears in my urls after a redirection from http to https.
for example,
the url http://www.quickinfo.co.il/page/804/?s=%D7%A7%D7%9F redirects to https://www.quickinfo.co.il/page/804/?s=%25D7%25A7%25D7%259F.
as you can see an additional "25" is getting added after every "%".
I tried almost every thing to remove it but still no luck (redirects don't seem to work here).

my htaccess that redirects the http to https looks like this:

```
RewriteCond m%{HTTP_HOST} ^quickinfo.co.il$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.quickinfo.co.il$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

maybe that's what causing the problem?

Comment: so how can i fix it and still keep redirecting the none www too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Starkeen said, the issue is the "%" character is being escaped.

You should add the [`NE` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) to your rewrite rule.

```
RewriteCond m%{HTTP_HOST} ^quickinfo.co.il$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.quickinfo.co.il$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```